# Not able to download file name containing 'aspx' character in asp .net

Tags: asp.net, .net, generics, handler, download

Am developing asp .Net web application.

In one of my aspx file am using file to download using generic handler. Everything works great. But when am testing i felt a strange problem. That, if am uploading a image or document with file name containing aspx character for Eg; aspxphoto as file name.
Uploading doesnt have any any problem but when i try to download it is throwing error in Generic handler file as

> Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Can anyone help me why this problem happends and how can i fix it?

Answer (score 0):

You will not be able to do this.  The IIS handler wants to "handle" the ASPX.  You should simply not allow it, or if you have to, rename it to .aspx.uploaded or something.  If you allowed, it you could open yourself to hacking.

As another option, you may be able to create a virtual that implements ("no processing") - possibly using the HTTP Handler under the virtual and just disabling script / execute permissions (under handler >> Edit Feature Permission >> Script OR under Virtual >> Edit permissions >> Special >> Turn Execute off.

I would not recommend the last, since it will add complexity when migrating between test and live AND for recovery (DR).

Comment: thanks for replying. Just for clarfication, you are proposing that i just want to push off clients from entering aspx related filename?

Comment: I am not saying push of, but just rename it then.  I think that allowing users to upload ASPX is not really a good idea.

Comment: Users not uploading aspx file. They are uploading any file with name include character aspx. That is the problem

Comment: That won't be a problem.  It will only be when the users uploads {filename}.aspx.  bob-aspx.txt should do nothing.

Comment: Thanks for your support Mr. Anthony. I found the problem. It was problem with my encryption of query string while downloading. Need to see it.

Comment: Cool.  The question problem didn't really make sense - in what I had seen to date.  Glad you got it sorted.